# Spring Boot and stop by systemctl not working

Tags: systemd, systemctl, springboot

My application uses Spring Boot 2.3.1.RELEASE, it is an executable jar that uses an Embedded Tomcat and is listening on port 10605.
I deployed on CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core).

I took the following steps:

1. SPEEDYF.service creation

[Unit]

Description=SPEEDYF

After=syslog.target

[Service]

User=root

ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/SPEEDYF/SPEEDYF.sh

SuccessExitStatus=143

[Install]

WantedBy=multi-user.target

2. creation of executable SPEEDYF.sh

#! / Bin / bash

sudo java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active = prod /usr/local/bin/SPEEDYF/SPEEDYF-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

For the first time the command: systemctl enable SPEEDYF.service
The start works correctly: systemctl start SPEEDYF.service

While the stop does not work properly: systemctl stop SPEEDYF.service.
That is, if I run the systemctl status SPEEDYF.service command I have the following output:

● SPEEDYF.service - SPEEDYF
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/SPEEDYF.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: inactive (dead) .........

But the application is still running, that is, it writes the application logs and then verifying with the command:

lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN

the TCP port 10605 results in LISTEN.

The commands are executed with the root user.
I don't understand what I can do to make the stop work properly.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you call a shell script instead of starting java directly?

Comment: First of all, you don't need *sudo* as service starts as root. Add *Type=simple* into unit file

Comment: Could you please show the result of `ps auxf`. If it too many information, just find you java process and detect the whole tree. It might be the process launched by another user/system.